# Access continuous portion of array using C

Tags: c, arrays

Using C programming, is it possible to access a specific continuous-portion from an  array without  using shift operator or loops .

If i need to access x number of continuous elements from an array of size n, (n>x). Will there be any chance to get them into another array that is x bits wide (as in HDL).

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show your attempts so far and post questions regarding specific problems that you encounter while writing this code.

Answer (score 1):

absolutely: just add!

Say you want to have acces the an array starting at alement `n`

```
foo a[100];
foo *b=a+n;
```

`b` is now a name for the array starting at position `n`,

On the other hand C doesn't do arrays of bits the smallest primitive type is char.
bit-ranges are a special case..... so no it's not possible to mimic in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memcpy`.

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

For example:

```
size_t x = ...; // the number of continuous elements to copy.
uint32_t src[n];
uint32_t dest[x];

memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(uint32_t) * x);
```

Also, be sure to include the `string.h` header.